# Why is const_iterator used instead of just iterator in this C++ question?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ exam question which doesn't make sense to me.

Question:

> Using the following library algorithms:
>
> - `find(b, e, v)` searches the range `[b, e)` and returns an iterator pointing at the first occurrence of `v`, if there is one, or `e` if there is not,
>
> 1. Write a function that takes a list of doubles and returns the number of
>   zeroes in the list. (15 marks)
>
> Answer:
>
> ```cpp
> int count_zeroes(const list<double> &l) {
>     return count(l.cbegin(), l.cend(), 0);
> }
> ```

My Question:

- Why is `cbegin()`/`cend()` used here instead of just `begin()`/`end()`?
- Why does the answer include a pass by reference to `&1` (is this specified in the question, perhaps)?
- Why was `list` made as a constant variable?

I got a similar answer but without the constant reference and I used pass by value instead.

Comment: With C++11 it doesn't matter in this case, begin()/end() will return const iterators anyways since the parameter is const.  Better to be explicit.

Comment: I understand that however this is an exam question and we are expected to write it out using pen and paper

Comment: There are multiple correct ways to do things, of course. But there can be ways that are better for specific reasons (technical, legibility, etc.), and style choices that don't much matter. Was your answer marked "wrong" in some way you don't understand? Or are you just asking why the given answer made those choices and how they might matter?

Comment: Why would you ever use non-const stuff if you could use const stuff?

Comment: @gct Are you referring to `cbegin`/`cend` not existing prior to C++11 or something else? From what I can tell `begin`/`end` would work here identically for all C++ versions, while `cbegin`/`cend` only does for C++11 and later but is otherwise identical.

Comment: @JMoss In your code it does not say `&1` (ampersand + digit one). It says `&l` (ampersand + lower-case character L). Check your font and use one that distinguishes them clearly.

Comment: Passing by const reference is usually "good style" in C++ (really depends on the type, and actually with C++11 it also changed slightly). I don't really understand how the given answer is related to the question (which sounds more like implementing `count` using only `find`). Btw: Pay attention not to mix up `1` and `l` (change your font if you can't distinguish them)

Comment: Some good reading on why prefer `const`: [Const Correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness)

Comment: I'll add `&1` to my list of reasons why one-letter identifiers are a bad, bad idea. Compiler would catch this one, though.

Comment: @walnut You're right I was mis-reading the reference, there was a begin() overload for const instances from the beginning.

Comment: Is the posted answer correct?  The answer doesn't use the `std::find` function; it uses `std::count`.

Comment: Wow thank you very much guys! found all comments to be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does the answer include a pass by reference to &1 (is this specified in the question, perhaps)?

To avoid creating unnecessary copy of entire list. Remember Objective is to only 'read' contents of list and count zeroes. This helps us in answering another question:

> Why was list made as a constant variable

Since we're only supposed to 'read' contents of list and passing by reference implies any change to list will be reflected back in original list. It is a good practice to pass such variables as `const` to prevent un-intentional changes.

> Why is cbegin()/cend() used here instead of just begin()/end()

Just found out, @NathanOliver is right. For completeness, pasting his comment here:
`begin` is overloaded for `const` objects to return a `const_iterator` so there is no need to actually use `cbegin` since `l` is `const`.

Comment: *Again, const iterator will prevent un-intentional changes.*, `begin` is overloaded for `const` objects to return a `const_iterator` so there is no need to actually use `cbegin` since `l` is const

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is cbegin()/cend() used here instead of just begin()/end() ?

NathanOliver has corrected me on this. It appears that there's no particular reason to use cbegin and cend in this case because the const data structure will return const iterators. It seems using cbegin, cend and begin,end will yield the same results.

> Why does the answer include a pass by reference to "&1" (is this
>   specified in the question, perhaps) ?

Passing potentially large data structures by reference is standard practice and efficient compared with passing by value and if you're not going to alter them then passing by const reference is the correct thing to do.

> why was 'list' made as a constant variable?

Because it isn't going to be altered inside the method. Using const to denote that something isn't allowed to be changed allows the compiler to apply optimisations it wouldn't be able to apply otherwise.

Comment: *You're not going to change the value the iterator refers to so const iterators are appropriate.* doesn't really answer the question.  `begin` is overloaded for `const` objects to return a `const_iterator` so there is no need to actually use `cbegin`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Interesting, I didn't know that. So the purpose of cbegin and cend is to stop modification of a non const data structure perhaps?

Comment: Yeah.  If you have a non-const vector and you want a const iterator then instead of using `const_cast` to get a const reference to the vector you can just call `cbegin` instead.